# Revoking Bluetooth permission from all apps?

Tags: adb, security, bluetooth, permissions, resource-monitoring

I noticed that my phone silently enables bluetooth when screen turns off. When phones remains inactive for few minutes and I click unlock button I can see bluetooth indicator showing up for around 1-2 seconds, then it disappears and Bluetooth is disabled. I have suspicions that some app enables bluetooth programatically when screen is off.

Can I revoke bluetooth permissions from all apps? (eg. using `adb`) Or at least check recent bluetooth activity events?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands:

```
adb shell
for package in $(pm list packages -3 | cut -f2 -d":"); do pm revoke $package android.permission.BLUETOOTH; pm revoke $package android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN; done
```

That will list every installed third party application then revoke both permissions `android.permission.BLUETOOTH` and `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`.

If you need to apply this to all installed and enabled applications, use `-e` instead of `-3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **System settings**⋙**Apps**, then click on the **3-dots ⋮** icon at the right-top corner of the title bar. Then, click on **Reset app preferences**, then click on **OK**.

Comment: There's no explicit Bluetooth permission in Android permissions settings - how could this operation help?

Comment: Yes, that is true, but the operation can revoke all permissions from all apps. You can give it a try.